# Column chart with negative values and categories on xAxis in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Well, I'm using highcharts in web app. 
Here is task to show Demographical data in column chart like on image :

[image]

What I have for now is just next example : http://jsfiddle.net/futw5e8k/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
    offset: -150
},

yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false,
    title: {
        text: 'Number of fruits'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
            'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
    }
},

plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [-3, -4, -4, -2, -5],
}]

});
```

Currently is problem with displaying `categories` in middle of graph with some space. In my example `offset` isn't generated according to data, so isn't for all cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two y axes that will have defined position using `top` and `height`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/futw5e8k/2/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
        offset: -150,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0
    },

    yAxis: [{
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits',
            y: 100,
            x: -10
        },
        top: 50,
        height: 124
    },{
      title: {
         text: null
        },
        top: 200,
        height: 150,
        offset: 0
    }],

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [-3, -4, -4, -2, -5],
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: for now it seems like what I want. Thanks ;)

Comment: Just one more question - How can I make height of columns be relative to both y-Axis ? Cause I need to hide labels on axis ... Now it looks like http://jsfiddle.net/futw5e8k/5/ As You may see, value 16 on negative side looks bigger than 20 on plus-side

Comment: Set max for positive axis and min for negative axis, probably will do the trick, but maybe there are more automatic solution...

Comment: @demo Unfortunately, I got nothing better than the mentioned min, max.