# Highchart with dynamic scale for both series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, scale

Question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552499/column-chart-with-negative-values-and-categories-on-xaxis-in-highcharts).

Problem : Currently I have chart with 2 series - one serie with positive and one with negative values. By default each serie has dynamic scaling but they are not relating (I mean if 20 for first serie is MAX value and 5 for second serie is MAX, then it looks on graph like the same). When I set max and min values to yAxis, it solve problem, but adds to much empty space, that for some cases column is too small. Can I update chart setting to have dynamic scalling but one for both series?

Here is my example with setted `MAX` and `MIN` values for `yAxis` http://jsfiddle.net/futw5e8k/6/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

title: {
    text: null
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['13-17', '18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45-54', '55-64', '65+'],
    offset: -150,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickWidth: 0
},

yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: null,
    },

    top: 50,
    height: 124,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
},{
        title: {
        text: null
    },
    top: 200,
    height: 150,
    offset: 0,
    min: -100,
    max: 0,
    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
    gridLineWidth: 0,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
}],

plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                crop: false,
                overflow: 'none',
                formatter: function() {
                        return Math.abs(this.y);
                        }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return this.x + '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + Math.abs(this.y);
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [1, 13, 20, 19, 15, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [-0.35, -6, -9, -16, -3, -1.5, -0.25]
}]
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On load event you can find the maximum of your data and dynamically update axes' max - see [Axis.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.update).

```
  chart: {
type: 'column',
events: {
  load: function() {
    const max = Math.max(this.series[0].dataMax, this.series[1].dataMax);

    this.yAxis[0].update({
      max: max,
    }, false);

    this.yAxis[1].update({
      max: max,
      top: 130
    }, false);

    this.redraw(false);
  }
}
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/futw5e8k/7/

Comment: For the negative y axis, needs to specify `min` rather than `max`. Also, @demo, you need to make sure that your axis `height`s are the same, or making the extremes match won't accomplish your goal.  Updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/futw5e8k/10/

Comment: One comment - for my case correct max will be `const max = Math.max(this.series[0].dataMax, Math.abs(this.series[1].dataMin));`